# Can't use the downloaded java file

Tags: java, file, build, path

[image]I am trying to write some code to use class from a downloaded java file. I saved them in the same folder and I can open the file with Eclipse. I noticed that there is a hollow "J" there, then I researched related problems online and knew that this is caused by the build path of files. Those methods told me to open the "properties" in "Project" section, but the icon is just grey and I cannot do anything with it!
How to solve this problem?
[image]

Comment: I don't see the `GeoLocation` in your package structure.

Comment: Where's the GeoLocation.java in your package? I can't see it. You probably didn't paste the file into your package. That's why the eclipse is unable to load it.

Comment: I put files into the default folder,  I guess it might be caused by the default package. I can find the downloaded file in the default package folder but can't see it in the package structure.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse does not automatically refresh changed content in the file system. You have to refresh the workspace whenever you edit/delete/add files directly in the file system. Right click on the project (or the subfolder) you want to refresh and choose 'refresh' (or F5).